# Way to make sure that an argument is used in *all* code paths?

Tags: swift

Let's say that I have a `NotificationManager` with this function:

```
func receivedRemoteNotification(userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler: UIBackgroundFetchResult -> Void) {
    guard isValidPayload(userInfo) else {
        fetchCompletionHandler(.Failed)
        return
    }

    doSomethingAsyncWithCompletionHandler(fetchCompletionHandler)
}
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that `fetchCompletionHandler` has to **always** be called, whatever the code path is?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `defer` block to specify some code to be execute before the current function ends.

```
func foo() {
    defer {
        print("This will always be printed before the end")
    }
    print("Some code")
}

foo()

> Some code
> This will always be printed before the end
```

So you can update your function this way

```
func receivedRemoteNotification(userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler: UIBackgroundFetchResult -> Void) {
    defer {
        // call fetchCompletionHandler here
    }

    guard isValidPayload(userInfo) else {
        fetchCompletionHandler(.Failed)
        return
    }

    fetchCompletionHandler(.NewData)
}
```

Of course pay attention to avoid multiple calls.

### Update

Swift has a mechanism to find out that every possible branch of your code do initialize a constant before being used.

You could take advantage of this technique declaring a constant that must be initialized

```
let result: UIBackgroundFetchResult
```

and adding a `defer` block where `fetchCompletionHandler` is invoked with the previous constant.

```
defer {
    fetchCompletionHandler(result)
}
```

Now the compiler will force you to populate `result` in every possible branch before the current function ends.

```
func receivedRemoteNotification(userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler: UIBackgroundFetchResult -> ()) {

    let result: UIBackgroundFetchResult
    defer {
        fetchCompletionHandler(result)
    }

    guard isValidPayload(userInfo) else {
        result = .Failed // if you remove this you get a compiler error
        return
    }
    result = .NewData // if you remove this you get a compiler error
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, though how to call the completion handler depends on the code path of the function, which is why I'd like that to be a warning from the compiler. Definitely a great option.

Comment: Yes, it's a very nice trick and perfectly answers the question as curently stated. What I forgot to add is that `fetchCompletionHandler` can be passed to another method to be executed later in an async call. So it's really about enforcing that the parameter is *used* in all code paths, not necessarily *called*. Updating my question, sorry about that.